# Resource recommendation for thermal transportation in solids

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations

I see there are many theories about transportation i.e. Einstein Debye, Boltzmann transportation theory, Landauer approach, Kubo formulas, Kyldesh/Green function formalism.

I am looking for an introductory book/article that explains these theories chronologically. I know, Kyldesh/Green functions are in itself are big topics and have many good resources to read. However, I want to get a feeling that what went wrong with the previous theory and what new the preceding theory brought. I am looking for a kind of review article/book of overall thermal (and/or electronic) transportation theories.